# Angular 8 CKEditor not working in Mat Dialog

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I am trying to run CKEditor in my Angular app, but I get an empty body.

Here is my effort:

I followed the documentation from this [Site](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html#quick-start)

I followed all the steps but in the end my Html looks like this:

```
<ckeditor _ngcontent-ng-cli-universal-c309="" data="<p>Hello, world!</p>" style="height: 300px;"></ckeditor>
```

Its empty and no error is given in the console.

I am using Angular Material and
I am opening this in the Dialog using MatDialog.

This works on the Page but not on the Dialog.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: can you create a stackblitz of same issues you are facing ?

Comment: I figured out the issue its not appearing in dialog but its working greatly in the page. So it must be some issue with mat dialog

Comment: @supernerd, Is this is issue fixed? what's wrong with mat-dialog box? I am also not able to load ckEditor in Mat dialog. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while, but maybe someone will find this answer useful. I switched to the Decoupled Document Editor and that seems to work.

Edit: However, just trying the ClassicEditor (because I need 'sourceEditing'-plugin that doesn't work for DecoupledEditor) and this also works using the guide below.

## Building your own CKEditor version

First note that you MUST install first the angular Module and import it in your module!

```js
import {BrowserModule, HammerModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {CKEditorModule} from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [CKEditorModule],
    exports: [...],
    entryComponents: [...],
    providers: [...],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

    constructor() {}
}
```

Then, the second step is to use a custom build based on the DecoupledDocumentEditor via the online builder. This
custom build can then be inserted in your project.

Note: the DecoupledDocumentEditor needs two extra things:

1. you need to provide a configuration object
2. you need to supply the editor

In the configuration object you need to supply

1. extra plugins (use a angular-service as a singleton!)
2. the configuration of the toolbar.

for instance, the configuration object could look like this:

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CKEditorGlobalsService {

    public static config = {
        extraPlugins: [TheUploadAdapterPlugin],
        toolbar: {
            items: [
                'heading',
                '|',
                'fontSize','fontFamily',
                '|',
                'bold','italic','underline','strikethrough','subscript','superscript','removeFormat',
                '|',
                'fontBackgroundColor','fontColor',
                '|',
                'alignment',
                '|',
                'numberedList','bulletedList',
                '|',
                'indent','outdent',
                '|',
                'todoList','link','blockQuote','imageUpload',
                '|',
                'insertTable','mediaEmbed','pageBreak','sourceEditing',
                '|',
                'undo','redo',
                '|',
                'codeBlock','specialCharacters'
            ]
        },
        language: 'nl'
    };

    constructor() {
    }

}
```

## DecoupledDocumentEditor

Create your own editor using the [builder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/). Make sure to choose the
**DecoupledDocumentEditor**.

[Tutorial](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/ui/document-editor.html)

After download: (isn't this already done online?!)

- unzip
- go to unzipped folder
- run `npm i`
- run `npm run-script build`
- take the files from the `build`-folder and add them to your project: folder `src/app/CKEditor`.

See [this post](https://malinda0610.medium.com/how-to-configure-ckeditor-5-html-text-editor-with-angular-9-a0597db18c80)

The config must be injected through the service (CKEditorGlobalsService.ts).

## Usage in a form

The Typescript:

```js
import * as DecoupledEditor from '../../../../CKEditor5CustomBuild/ckeditor';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog-add-workflow',
  templateUrl: './dialog-edit-workflow.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog-edit-workflow.component.css', '../ckEditorOverrides.css']
})
export class DialogEditWorkflowComponent implements OnInit {
    public ckEditorInstance = DecoupledEditor;
    public ckconfig = CKEditorGlobalsService.config;

    public onReady(editor: DecoupledEditor.Editor): void {
        editor['ui'].getEditableElement().parentElement.insertBefore(
            editor['ui'].view.toolbar.element,
            editor['ui'].getEditableElement()
        );
    }
}
```

The HTML template:

```html
      <div>
        <label>Interventie informatie</label>
        <ckeditor [config]="ckconfig"
                  [editor]="ckEditorInstance"
                  formControlName="interventionInfo"
                  (ready)="onReady($event)"></ckeditor>
      </div>
```